# Angular 6 - Custom Control Inside Reactive Form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an Angular Component with a reactive form.
The form model has a list of `users`.
Each `user` has a specific model, so my thought was to give them their own component and then add the component (in form of a list) to the form like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input 
    matInput 
    required 
    placeholder="Budget" 
    autocorrect="on" 
    autocapitalize="off" 
    spellcheck="on" 
    formControlName="budget">
</mat-form-field>

<app-project-users 
  [projectUsers]="projectForm.get('users').value" 
  (changedProjectUsers)="changedProjectUsers($event)">
</app-project-users>
```

Is this the correct approach?
I will then have a model, a formsModel, and every extra component "formModel" to handle in the forms ngSubmit method, which looks a bit hacky....
I couldn't find anything in the official documentation neither on the web about these type of problems.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `FormArray` to implement this. In the parent component where you create the `formGroup` you should have something like:

```
this.fb.group({
    users: this.fb.array()
})
```

You then add either a `FormGroup` or `FormControl` to the array for each of the users. `app-project-users` is then responsible for adding/removing groups/control from the array.

There is tutorial for form arrays on [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays) and you can find more examples when you google for 'angular form arrays'.

Second approach is that your `app-project-users` will implement `ControlValueAccessor` and becomes `FormControl` itself and its model will be array of users.

Comment: Thank you Ludevik. Your answer was precious pointing the way to this post: https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83